# window getcomputedstyle failed to execute 'getcomputedstyle'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have my website developed in core PHP I used JS to make my website responsive.
I am getting this error at my login page **https://varsitypartner.com/login.php**

```
main.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at checkMQ (main.js:91)
    at moveNavigation (main.js:95)
    at HTMLDocument.$.ready (main.js:13)
    at l (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.S (jquery.min.js:4)
```

My Js Function where it is showing error:

```
function checkMQ() {
        //check if mobile or desktop device
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.main-content'),'::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");
    }
```

How to remove this error.

Comment: The error says `document.querySelector('.main-content')` doesn't select any element, i.e. when that line is executed there is no element with class of `main-content`.

Comment: make sure that the function get executed after the dom is ready